# Why ErrorHandler component is not registering properly in SlingMainServlet?

Tags: error-handling, aem, sling

I have a simple component for my own ErrorHandler implementation:

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
@Properties(
        @Property(name = "service.ranking", intValue = 1)
)
public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(int status, String message, SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        handleError(status, request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable throwable, SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        handleError(505, request, response);
    }

    private void handleError(int status, SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (status != 200) {
            try {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/etc/errors/" + status + ".html").forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No error pages");
            }
    }
}
```

If I deploy the component to Sling, nothings happen until restart of whole Sling. It's not a good solution I  guess.

#### Short explanation about using ErrorHandler instead of handling scripts (for those who would ask 'why you didn't use overloaded script)

1. Writing own Servlet is too complex for that easy behaviour
2. Scripts are less maintainable than java code (in sling).

Comment: Does this replace the default error handler? And do you know what this error handler is called?